# Purpose of string & keyof Type in typescript template literals

Tags: typescript

I am reading the typescript handbook ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)) and came across this example for adding an "onChange" function to the properties of a type ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAUQG4QHbAMoIK5wDGEAPACrgQB8UAvFAN4BQUrUCGAFBOlgHIBDALYQAXFAAGAEgYBnYHACWGAOZQAZFADWEEAgBmUCpAC%20AYQAWA1RAAmEgDRRCAgDauARgMJbxnDBAA7gBqbnhiUNYgAJR0NKgIirbR4glJANxMJplMAPT5UGZwEALA0AJQAESBpYQWduweAFYQhMCVUIGKwBaRGFAA5BwDUCI9CLZ5BbIIUD2lUHp4ztadtb36CHDOVjayc7NgiJBwwIoQsgB0TLatrgLFUPp4GG2KHKMCOgDq63YA8s1WsByJQqJwEM1xMYICkjJQNLBjmhMDh8ERSDCqOkgA))

```
type PropEventSource<Type> = {
    on(eventName: `${string & keyof Type}Changed`, callback: (newValue: any) => void): void;
};
/// Create a "watched object" with an 'on' method
/// so that you can watch for changes to properties.
declare function makeWatchedObject<Type>(obj: Type): Type & PropEventSource<Type>;
```

But I do not understand why the "string &" part is necessary. I.e. what is the type error saying when we write

```
on(eventName: `${keyof Type}Changed`, callback: (newValue: any) => void): void;
```

?

According to the `keyof` documentation it returns a string or numeric literal. So what is the point of adding string &?

Comment: Just added the link! Thanks.

Comment: "what is the type error saying when we write" You can try this yourself, right in the playground link you provided. Just delete the `string &`, the error message pop right up.

Answer (score 5):

`keyof X` does not always resolve to `string`. Keys can be strings, numbers, or Symbols. The `string &` restriction prevents including `Changed` event names for number- or Symbol-keyed properties of `Type`. That's why when you remove it, you get an error about the `symbol` and `number` types.

Here's an example:

```typescript
const obj = {
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]: () => 42,
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    42: 42,
};

const x = makeWatchedObject(obj);
x.on()
//   ^−−− eventName is shown as "xChanged" | "yChanged", it doesn't have the
//        Symbol property or the 42 property.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)